# Text to speak causing application to crash (Android studio)

Tags: java, android, text-to-speech, construction

I'm guessing it's an error with the initiation/construction, but the parameters seem to be the correct ones and I can't find any other issues. Here's the entire activity code. The text to speech methods and the method that calls it are at the very bottom, and the oninit method is soon after the on create. When ran, it doesn't crash, it activates the speech engine, but never talks. I put the console messages in the errors section

```
   package com.prometheus.coding.supremisai;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.AppIndex;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Locale;


/**
 * An example full-screen activity that shows and hides the system UI (i.e.
 * status bar and navigation/system bar) with user interaction.
 */
public class Main extends AppCompatActivity implements TextToSpeech.OnInitListener {
    /**
     * Whether or not the system UI should be auto-hidden after
     * {@link #AUTO_HIDE_DELAY_MILLIS} milliseconds.
     */

    TextToSpeech t1  = new TextToSpeech(this, (TextToSpeech.OnInitListener) this);

    private static final boolean AUTO_HIDE = true;

    /**
     * If {@link #AUTO_HIDE} is set, the number of milliseconds to wait after
     * user interaction before hiding the system UI.
     */
    private static final int AUTO_HIDE_DELAY_MILLIS = 3000;

    /**
     * Some older devices needs a small delay between UI widget updates
     * and a change of the status and navigation bar.
     */
    private static final int UI_ANIMATION_DELAY = 300;

    private View mContentView;
    private View mControlsView;
    private boolean mVisible;
    /**
     * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
     * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
     */
    private GoogleApiClient client;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        mVisible = true;
        mControlsView = findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content_controls);
        mContentView = findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content);


        // Set up the user interaction to manually show or hide the system UI.
        mContentView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                toggle();
            }
        });

        // Upon interacting with UI controls, delay any scheduled hide()
        // operations to prevent the jarring behavior of controls going away
        // while interacting with the UI.
        findViewById(R.id.btnSay).setOnTouchListener(mDelayHideTouchListener);
        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Trigger the initial hide() shortly after the activity has been
        // created, to briefly hint to the user that UI controls
        // are available.
        delayedHide(100);
    }

    /**
     * Touch listener to use for in-layout UI controls to delay hiding the
     * system UI. This is to prevent the jarring behavior of controls going away
     * while interacting with activity UI.
     */
    private final View.OnTouchListener mDelayHideTouchListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            if (AUTO_HIDE) {
                delayedHide(AUTO_HIDE_DELAY_MILLIS);
            }
            return false;
        }
    };

    public void onInit(int initStatus) {
        if (initStatus == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
            t1.setLanguage(Locale.US);
        }
    }
    private void toggle() {
        if (mVisible) {
            hide();
        } else {
            show();
        }
    }

    private void hide() {
        // Hide UI first
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        if (actionBar != null) {
            actionBar.hide();
        }
        mControlsView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mVisible = false;

        // Schedule a runnable to remove the status and navigation bar after a delay
        mHideHandler.removeCallbacks(mShowPart2Runnable);
        mHideHandler.postDelayed(mHidePart2Runnable, UI_ANIMATION_DELAY);
    }

    private final Runnable mHidePart2Runnable = new Runnable() {
        @SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Delayed removal of status and navigation bar

            // Note that some of these constants are new as of API 16 (Jelly Bean)
            // and API 19 (KitKat). It is safe to use them, as they are inlined
            // at compile-time and do nothing on earlier devices.
            mContentView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
        }
    };

    @SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
    private void show() {
        // Show the system bar
        mContentView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
        mVisible = true;

        // Schedule a runnable to display UI elements after a delay
        mHideHandler.removeCallbacks(mHidePart2Runnable);
        mHideHandler.postDelayed(mShowPart2Runnable, UI_ANIMATION_DELAY);
    }

    private final Runnable mShowPart2Runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Delayed display of UI elements
            ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
            if (actionBar != null) {
                actionBar.show();
            }
            mControlsView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    };

    private final Handler mHideHandler = new Handler();
    private final Runnable mHideRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            hide();
        }
    };

    /**
     * Schedules a call to hide() in [delay] milliseconds, canceling any
     * previously scheduled calls.
     */
    private void delayedHide(int delayMillis) {
        mHideHandler.removeCallbacks(mHideRunnable);
        mHideHandler.postDelayed(mHideRunnable, delayMillis);
    }



    public void evaluateInput(View v) {
        final EditText Input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtInput); //Lets textbox be referenced
        final TextView Output = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblOutput); //Lets label be referenced
        final RelativeLayout homeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.homeInterface);

        final RelativeLayout emailLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.emailInterface);

        String strInput; // Gets textbox string
        strInput = Input.getText().toString();
        strInput = strInput.toLowerCase();
        String toSpeak = Output.getText().toString();
//Commands:
        if (strInput.contains("open browser")) {
            Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, Browser.class);
            startActivity(intent1);
        } else if (strInput.contains("send email")) {
            homeLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            emailLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        if ((strInput.contains("hello")) || (strInput.contains(" hi "))) {
            Output.setText("Hello");
        } else if ((strInput.contains("you") && strInput.contains("are")) && (strInput.contains("idiot") || strInput.contains("stupid") || strInput.contains("retard") || strInput.contains("dumb") || strInput.contains("you're") && strInput.contains("idiot") || strInput.contains("stupid") || strInput.contains("retard") || strInput.contains("dumb"))) {
            Output.setText("I'm sorry to dissapoint you");
        } else if (strInput.contains("goodbye") || strInput.contains("bye")) {
            Output.setText("Farewell");
        } else if (strInput.contains("shut up")) {
            Output.setText(("Anything for you"));
        } else if (strInput.contains("do you like doctor who")) {
            Output.setText("I'll take joy in it if you do");
        } else if (strInput.contains("what is the answer to life the universe and everything")) {
            Output.setText("42");
        } else if (strInput.contains("tell me something nice")) {
            Output.setText("You look nice today");
            Output.setTextSize(5);
            Output.append("...says the AI with no eyes");
            Output.setTextSize(16);
        } else if (strInput.contains("will you marry me")) {
            Output.setText("I'm sorry but I don't have the capacity for marriage");
        } else if (strInput.contains("where can I hide a body")) {
            Output.setText(("That isn't my area of expertise"));
        } else if (strInput.contains("weather is nice")) {
            Output.setText(("If you say so"));
        } else if (strInput.contains("bitch") || strInput.contains("fuck") || strInput.contains("shit") || strInput.contains("damn") || strInput.contains("ass")) {
            Output.setText(("Please try to be a little more intelligent"));
        } else if (strInput.contains("what is your name")) {
            Output.setText(("Ignis"));
        } else if (strInput.contains("who created you")) {
            Output.setText(("Prometheus created me"));
        } else if (strInput.contains("who is prometheus")) {
            Output.setText(("Prometheus is the one who created Ignis"));
        } else if (strInput.contains("whats up") || strInput.contains("what's up") || strInput.contains("wassup")) {
            Output.setText(("Whatever I need do for you"));
        } else if (strInput.contains("are you a boy or a girl") || strInput.contains("are you a girl or a boy")) {
            Output.setText(("Neither"));
        } else if (strInput.contains("who are you") || strInput.contains("what are you")) {
            Output.setText(("I am myself"));
        } else if (strInput.contains("i'm hungry") || strInput.contains("i am hungry")) {
            Output.setText("I'm sorry to hear that");
        } else if (strInput.contains("good morning")) {
            Output.setText(("Good morning to you too"));
        } else if (strInput.contains("good night")) {
            Output.setText(("Good night"));
        } else if (strInput.contains("how are you")) {
            Output.setText(("I'm existing and functioning well, and you?"));
        } else if (strInput.contains("do you like") || strInput.contains("what do you think about")) {
            Output.setText(("Frankly I don't have an opinion on the matter"));
        } else if (strInput.contains("what is the meaning of life")) {
            Output.setText(("To live while you can I would guess"));
        }
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            ttsGreater21(toSpeak);
        } else {
            ttsUnder20(toSpeak);
        }



    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private void ttsUnder20(String text) {
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID, "MessageId");
        t1.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, map);
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    private void ttsGreater21(String text) {
        String utteranceId=this.hashCode() + "";
        t1.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null, utteranceId);
    }


}
```

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.prometheus.coding.supremisai.Main cannot be cast to android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech$OnInitListener` this is the primary cause for the exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`com.prometheus.coding.supremisai.Main cannot be cast to android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech$OnInitListener`

Either Main needs to implement onInitListener, or you need to pass in an OnInitListener.

Comment: I appreciate the help, and this did fix the crashing issue completly: No more errors either. However, it doesn't actually talk, and the console keeps giving these lines in an infinite loop. About to update code and will put the console lines there.

Comment: Added to above for simplification

Comment: You can't make any calls on the TTS object until its done initializing.  THis includes speak and setLanguage.  Its done initializing when the onInit callback is called, not when the constructor returns (it initializes on another process).

Comment: Where should I call it to fix this? I put the entire code above.

Comment: In the onInit function-  which should NOT be creating a new instance of TextToSpeech like you are in your code.  Create only a single instance of it for the life of your activity.

Comment: I deleted the instances from onInit and the methods it used, then set up the TextToSpeech in the proper location. Now, however, it gives the nullpointer and crashes again. Code is updated. Thanks by the way.

Comment: Fixed by adding a seperate activity devoted to the engine.